# jQuery Masonry causing large gaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying to create a jQuery Masonry project and I am having issues when resizing from very large to very small quickly, it creates a huge gap vertically. I put in a fix, that essentially after .5 seconds recalls .masonry() which is a hack and a half. Anyone have any idea?

http://jsbin.com/uZEqACI/1/

remove the setTimeout hooked into smartresize and resize the page quickly and you can see.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have tried setInterval

Comment: Won't that slow the site down? With a constant interval running?